# get postgreSQL client computer name

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way in postgres to `SELECT` the current clients name? I wish to create an audit field using the clients computer name.

Comment: SELECT inet_client_addr(); or 
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE client_addr = inet_client_addr();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
select * 
from pg_stat_activity 
where pid = pg_backend_pid();
```

`client_hostname` And `client_addr` are relevant.

`log_hostname` needs enabling in order for the name to be resolved correctly. See [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-HOSTNAME):

> By default, connection log messages only show the IP address of the
>   connecting host. Turning this parameter on causes logging of the host
>   name as well. Note that depending on your host name resolution setup
>   this might impose a non-negligible performance penalty. This parameter
>   can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server command
>   line.

Comment: Mine is `null` when i ran this

Comment: Is "yours" a local socket connection, perchance?

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch: to see the hostname you need to enable [log_hostname](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-HOSTNAME)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've edited my answer with that. Thank you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Upon doing some digging, I found my `postgresql.conf` and uncommented `log_hostname = off` and changed it to `log_hostname = on`. However I still have a null hostname. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. I ran a `sudo reboot` and it worked after that

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch:  a simple restart of the postgres service would have been enough.